# Postgres, get unique records per day from date range select

Tags: json, postgresql, distinct-values

I need to make a report with logged users by date range but without duplicates on the same day (if someone was logged twice on the same day we won't list it twice). unfortunately, we keep login information as json (yeah, I can't change it to separate table, I don't know who designed this db).
Query to see all logged user:

```
select a.id, username, email, ah.modified as login_date
from accounts a join
     account_history ah
     on modified_acc_id = a.id
 where ah.data::jsonb->>'message' = 'Logon';
```

Modified is timestamp with timezone and it is used as login date.

I found only examples with the count distinct ids per day but I don't know how to modified it to return distinct results per day

sample data:

```
 id  |        username  |              email       |         login_date
-----+-------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------
 102 | example          | example@example.com      | 2018-12-06 09:30:10.573+00
 102 | example          | example@example.com      | 2018-12-06 09:32:34.235+00
  42 | rafal            | rafal@example.com        | 2018-12-06 09:45:24.884+00
 576 | john             | john@example.com         | 2018-12-06 09:35:24.922+00
 576 | john             | john@example.com         | 2018-12-07 09:58:04.253+00
```

wanted data:

```
 id  |        username  |              email       |         login_date
-----+-------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------
 102 | example          | example@example.com      | 2018-12-06 09:30:10.573+00
  42 | rafal            | rafal@example.com        | 2018-12-06 09:45:24.884+00
 576 | john             | john@example.com         | 2018-12-06 09:35:24.922+00
 576 | john             | john@example.com         | 2018-12-07 09:58:04.253+00
```

So as you can see, without second row

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` gives you exactly the first row of an ordered group. In your example the group is the `id` and the `date` part of the `login_date` timestamp

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, login_date::date)
    *
FROM (
    -- <your query>
) s
ORDER BY id, login_date::date, login_date
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c7602479d5162c5d1f113288d2d4e94c)

Explanation of `ORDER BY` clause:

You have to order by the `DISTINCT` columns first. But in your case you don't really want to order by date only but by its time part too. So after ordering by date (which is necessary because of your `DISTINCT` columns) you have to order by timestamp as well.

---

So the whole query could be simplified to (without subquery):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id, ah.modified::date) 
    a.id, 
    username, 
    email, 
    ah.modified as login_date
FROM accounts a 
JOIN account_history ah
    ON modified_acc_id = a.id
WHERE ah.data::jsonb->>'message' = 'Logon'
ORDER BY a.id, ah.modified::date, ah.modified
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the number of user-days for a period of time.  If I understand correctly:

```
select count(*) as num_user_days_in_range
from (select a.username, date_trunc('day', ah.modified) as login_date
      from accounts a join
           account_history ah
           on modified_acc_id = a.id
      where ah.data::jsonb->>'message' = 'Logon'
      group by a.username, login_date
     ) u
where login_date >= $date1 and login_date < $date2
```

Comment: I edited my question, I don't want the number of users, just distinct users per day

Answer (score 0):

use window function `row_number()`

```
select id,username,email,login_date from 
(
 select a.id, username, email, ah.modified as login_date,
row_number() over(partition by a.id, username,email order by ah.modified) rn
 from accounts a join
 account_history ah
 on modified_acc_id = a.id
 where ah.data::jsonb->>'message' = 'Logon'
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as through when there is a dupe, you are taking the earliest date.  If that's the case, does this work?

```
select
  a.id, username, email, min (ah.modified) as login_date
from accounts a join
     account_history ah
     on modified_acc_id = a.id
 where ah.data::jsonb->>'message' = 'Logon'
group by a.id, username, email, ah.modified::date
```